# Error RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge: Your request header section exceeds the maximum allowed size NEXTJS NODEJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
    const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY,
  region: process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION,
});


const uploadBase64 = (bucketName, filePath,fileName, userId) => {
  const base64Data = new Buffer.from(fileName.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
  const type = fileName.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: `${filePath}/${userId}/${fileName}`,
    Body: base64Data,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: `image/${type}`,
  };

  return s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
    }
  })
  
  
};
```

I'm trying send base64 format image to AWS S3 Bucket and i didn't add anything to the header. I can't see what's in the header. Gives me this error

```
Error RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge: Your request header section exceeds the maximum allowed size.
    at Request.extractError (/home/sola-serkan/Desktop/social/back/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:711:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/sola-serkan/Desktop/social/back/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge',
}
```